# Eliminar URLs en una cadena de Texto

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, xamarin, url

Estoy intentando obtener los URLs (de momento de YouTube) cuando se postee una cadena de texto.

La lógica actual es:

> 1. Buscar si la cadena contiene `youtube.com/`, si lo lleva entonces (2.) Si no, entonces salir.
> 2. Obtener el texto desde `youtube.com/` hasta el primer espacio que encuentre `" "` despues de `youtube.com` .

Metodo:

```
public bool ValidarURL(string url)
        {            
            if (url.Contains("https://www.youtube.com/") || url.Contains("youtube.com/") )
            {
                OnlyURL = url.Substring(url.IndexOf("youtube.com/"), url.IndexOf(" "));
                OnlyURL = ("https://www." + OnlyURL).ToString();
                return Android.Util.Patterns.WebUrl.Matcher(OnlyURL).Matches();
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }            
        }
```

Pero me encantaria poder hacerlo de esta forma mas estandar:

> 1. Buscar si la cadena contiene `youtube.com/`, si lo lleva entonces (2.) Si no, entonces salir.
> 2. Obtener el texto desde el primer espacio antes de `youtube.com/` hasta el primer espacio despues de `youtube.com/`.

Esto con la finalidad de ELIMINAR la URL de la cadena de texto original. Logrando algo asi:

Texto original:

> Hola amigos, vean este video [www.YouTube.com/mivideoID](http://www.YouTube.com/mivideoID) se los
> recomiendo.

Texto a obtener:

> Hola amigos, vean este video se los recomiendo.

Comment: Puedes utilizar expresiones regulares para obtener los registros que hacen match y luego reemplazar los match por espacios en blanco o nada dentro de la cadena de texto original.
La expresión regular seria algo como esto según tus necesidades: ````(http[s]?:\/\/|www\.)[^\s]+````

Comment: No te comprendi.

Comment: ¿No sabes lo que es una expresión regular? [Revisa este enlace](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular) de wikipedia. ¿No sabes como utilizarlas en C#? [Revisa esta guia](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) de microsoft

Comment: Solo deseas eliminar la url de Youtube o cualquiera KenniAli?¿

Comment: @Jorgesys Solo la de YouTube

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar una REGEX para eliminar los urls,

Si necesitas un **`REGEX` para eliminar todos los url** usa:

```
      texto = Regex.Replace(texto, @"((http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?)", "");
```

Si necesitas un **`REGEX` para eliminar los url de Youtube** usa:

```
   texto = Regex.Replace(texto, @"((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)", "");
```

Comment: Una consulta: El metodo funciona excelente, pero queria consultarte si seria posible utilizarlo para almacenar la URL en una variable antes de eliminarla. De momento lo hago pero mi metodo es mas largo que esa linea ya que tengo que validar si es http, https, www., etc... Gracias.